# when to use -f or -a tag in if loop

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm confused between two tages that can be used in `if` statement in bash scripting.

One is `-f` and other is `-a`.

Their description states as follows:

```
[ -f FILE ] True if FILE exists and is a regular file.
[ -a FILE ] True if FILE exists.
```

Now, while using the if condition in my shell script how can I know which tag should I use. Like I have a script which takes regular backups using `tar` and creates a file `file-name.tar.gz` so how can I know which is a regular file. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Regular files** are all the text or data file, it can be a binary file as well. For regular files the output of `ls -l` would be like,

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 username group 74 Nov 27 16:03 mytext.txt
```

In general the first place for a regular file a `-` should appear. In such cases `if [ -f FILE ]` would be appropriate.

**Non-Regular files** are devices, pipes, sockets, tty etc. all other that fall under "Everything is a file" philosophy as pointed out by drc. You can go through [Unix_file_types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_file_types) for more information.

You can verify the `ls -l` output of some like,

```
crw-rw---- 1 root tty 4, 1 Dec  9 13:41 /dev/tty1
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 1, 11 Dec  9 13:41 /dev/ram11
```

For all the non-regular files you should use `if [ -a FILE ]`

Comment: Though symbolic links are non-regular, `if [ -f FILE ]` works for them. see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858452/what-is-a-regular-file-on-unix/6858520#6858520)

Answer (score 1):

For tar files – and basically any other file you create – `-f` is the correct choice.

`-a` is for special files like device nodes, fifos and such, which according to the Unix philosophy of [Everything is a file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file) are presented as files in your filesystem.